# cannot add Database.HDBC.Sqlite3 to stack file

Tags: haskell, hdbc

I am trying to implement the database using both libs `HDBC` and `HDBC-sqlite3`, while I am getting error for adding `HDBC-Sqlie3` and  I have tried the below :

- HDBC-Sqlite3
- HDBC-Sqlite3 -any
- HDBC-Sqlite3  >= 2.3.3.0 && < 2.3.3.1
- HDBC-Sqlite3 >= 2.3.3.0

and none of the above works and getting the error, when try the `- any` I got the following error :

```
In the dependencies for blog-post-0.1.0.0:
HDBC-Sqlite3 must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version
```

edit :

[stack.yaml file](https://github.com/kwaleko/blog-post/blob/master/stack.yaml)

[cabal file](https://github.com/kwaleko/blog-post/blob/master/blog-post.cabal)

Comment: Please post your _*.cabal_ and your _stack.yaml_ files. Without them it's difficult to help you.

Comment: If you add a package to the extra-deps section of the stack.yaml file, you have to give an exact version. ``HDBC-Sqlite3-2.3.3.0``

Comment: I have tried this as well, same issue. also the files are uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main error was the uppercase **S** in HDBC-**s**qlite3!

This should be the library section of your cabal file

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , parsec >= 3.1.11 && < 4
                     , servant
                     , servant-client
                     , servant-server
                     , aeson >= 1.1
                     , mtl
                     , HDBC >=2.4 && <3.0
                     , HDBC-sqlite3 >= 2.3.3.0
```

and this should be the *extra-deps* section of your stack.yaml file:

```
# Dependency packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver
# (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps:
- HDBC-sqlite3-2.3.3.0
```

You must add the package HDBC-sqlite3-2.3.3.0
to the extra-deps section of the stack.yaml file because it is missing in the set of packages of Stackage LTS-9.9.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and got ` Some extra-deps are neither installed nor in the index` and then tried to install it using stack install but same issue

Comment: Please commit the new versions of your cabal and stack.yaml files to your Git repo.

Comment: Updated. Thank you, just I have updated and put it in [String] in the `stack.yaml` file since it won't be parsed otherwise

Comment: Strange..., I downloaded you repo, did a ``stack setup`` and a ``stack build`` and it installed packages. I got an error, because I don't have installed the binaries of sqlite3. I'm using version 1.5.1 of stack.

Comment: I update the code to files ( cabal and stack) the version `2.3.3.0` and it works!